# Alignment of radio buttons in different radio lists

Tags: dm-script

all
I'd like to create two radio lists. Each list has two radio items. But the radio buttons of the second items are not aligned. Here is the code and screen shot. The radio button of dm4 and No are not aligned.

[image: Show example]

```
// Creating radio of format
TagGroup Dm3OrDm4, Dm3OrDm4Items
Dm3OrDm4 = DLGCreateRadioList(Dm3OrDm4Items,0).DLGAnchor("West")
Dm3OrDm4.DLGIdentifier( "#Dm3OrDm4" )
Dm3OrDm4Items.DLGAddRadioItem("dm3", 0).DLGSide("Left")
Dm3OrDm4Items.DLGAddRadioItem("dm4", 1).DLGSide("Left")
Dm3OrDm4.DLGTableLayOut(2,2,1)

// Creating radio of subfolder
TagGroup Subfolder, SubfolderItems
Subfolder = DLGCreateRadioList(SubfolderItems,1).DLGAnchor("West")
Subfolder.DLGIdentifier( "#Subfolder" )
SubfolderItems.DLGAddRadioItem("Yes", 0).DLGSide("Left")
SubfolderItems.DLGAddRadioItem("No", 1).DLGSide("Left")
Subfolder.DLGTableLayOut(2,1,1)

// Create box of conversion method
TagGroup Method, MethodItems
Method = DLGCreateBox("Method",MethodItems)
MethodItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("Output format").DLGAnchor("East"))
MethodItems.DLGAddElement(Dm3OrDm4)
MethodItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("Output to subfolder").DLGAnchor("East"))
MethodItems.DLGAddElement(Subfolder)
Method.DLGTableLayOut(2,2,1)
```

I tried to use DLGCreateRadioItem instead of DLGAddRadioItem. But it doesn't work.

```
TagGroup Dm3OrDm4Group, Dm3OrDm4GroupItems
Dm3OrDm4Group = DLGCreateGroup( Dm3OrDm4GroupItems ).DLGAnchor("East")
Dm3OrDm4Group.DLGIdentifier( "#Dm3OrDm4" )
Dm3OrDm4GroupItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateRadioItem("dm3", 0))
Dm3OrDm4GroupItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("dm3"))
Dm3OrDm4GroupItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateRadioItem("dm4", 1))
Dm3OrDm4GroupItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("dm4"))
Dm3OrDm4Group.DLGLayout( DLGCreateTableLayout( 4, 1, 0 ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to automatically "align" these items on a grid, as they are not part of the same "table". This becomes clearer, when looking at the actual taggroup describing the dialog:

[image: Dialog Description Taggroup]

The only thing to align them is by manually tweaking the "width" of the individual radio-items so that they match up. This can best be done by using `DLGInternalPadding` and `DLGExternalPadding`.

f.e. like this:

```c
class Dlg:UIFrame
{
    Taggroup CreateDLGTagGroup(object self)
    {
        // Creating radio of format
        TagGroup Dm3OrDm4, Dm3OrDm4Items
        Dm3OrDm4 = DLGCreateRadioList(Dm3OrDm4Items,0)
        Dm3OrDm4.DLGIdentifier( "#Dm3OrDm4" )
        Dm3OrDm4Items.DLGAddRadioItem("dm3", 0).DLGSide("Left")
        Dm3OrDm4Items.DLGAddRadioItem("dm4", 1)
    
        // Creating radio of subfolder
        TagGroup Subfolder, SubfolderItems
        Subfolder = DLGCreateRadioList(SubfolderItems,1)
        Subfolder.DLGIdentifier( "#Subfolder" )
        SubfolderItems.DLGAddRadioItem("Yes ", 0).DLGSide("Left").DLGExternalPadding(1,0)
        SubfolderItems.DLGAddRadioItem("No", 1)
        subfolder.DLGSide("Left")
    
        // Create box of conversion method
        TagGroup Method, MethodItems
        Method = DLGCreateBox("Method",MethodItems)
        MethodItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("Output format").DLGAnchor("East"))
        MethodItems.DLGAddElement(Dm3OrDm4.DLGAnchor("West"))
        MethodItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("Output to subfolder").DLGAnchor("East"))
        MethodItems.DLGAddElement(Subfolder.DLGAnchor("West"))
        Method.DLGTableLayOut(2,2,0)
        
        return method
    }

    void Show(object self)
    {
        self.init( self.CreateDLGTagGroup() ).display("Test (new)")
    }
} 

Alloc(dlg).Show()
```

[image: Comparison]